# How to make two fields depend on each other using JAXB or JAX-WS Annotation?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

Is there a way to make two fields depend on each other using JAXB or JAX-WS Annotation?
The fields are both not required, but if one exist then the other must also exist.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap these two field as required field under an optional field.

```
  <optionalTag>
        <Required1></Required1>
        <Required2></Required2>
  </optionalTag>
```

Comment: I had to implement for a specific structure. So I did the validation manually with java code, and throw an exception in the case that only one of the fields coming.

Comment: Ok,That will be the only solution if ur structure is fixed. I don't think so any annotation is available for thsi kind of check. Another option will be to apply a script on UI to force user to enter another field if one's existing like we see in various web forms.